# Get multiple Textfield values in array in swift (Xcode)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uitextfield

I have 10 textfields in my storyboard and I want to fetch values of them and store it into an array using loops so that I don't want to write hard code for each textfield using swift 4 (Xcode)
`.      var arr = [Int]()                                                    let val1 = Int(TxtVal1.text ?? "0") ?? 0 let val2 = Int(TxtVal2.text ?? "0") ?? 0 let val3 = Int(TxtVal3.text ?? "0") ?? 0 let val4 = Int(TxtVal4.text ?? "0") ?? 0 let val5 = Int(TxtVal5.text ?? "0") ?? 0 arr = [val1,val2,val3,val4,val5]`

don't want to do it like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@IBOutlet` collection. Bind your all `UITextField` with the `@IBOutlet` collection.

Example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var textFields: [UITextField]!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let arrTextValue = textFields.compactMap{Int($0.text ?? "0")}
        
        print(arrTextValue)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks that was the most easiest way...!

Answer (score 0):

You can assign tags to the UITextField and then store that textfield's value to array.

Set the tags to textfields

```
    txtField1.tag = 101
    txtField1.tag = 102
    //and so on
```

Create and initialise array to store text of textfields

```
    var arrText = [String]()


    //textfield tag are set from 101 to 110
    
    for tag in 101...110 {
        
        if let txtField = view.viewWithTag(tag) as? UITextField, let txt = txtField.text {
            arrText.append(txt)
        }
    }

print("array = \(arrText)")
```